# A simple C# GUI for ROS

Tags: ros, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

I wonder that if there is any possibility to write a simple Web-based or desktop-based GUI in C# for ROS. To be more clearer,foe example, if I write a simple desktop GUI in C# with Mono, How can I make connection with this desktop application and ROS? Do I use Rosbridge? How?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202491/a-simple-c#-gui-for-ros/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the easiest by far is probably making use of [ros_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite). That will allow you to interact with a ROS node graph using JSON messages. No (direct) ROS dependencies in your C# application, and it would also make it possible to run it on Windows.

An alternative might be to use an actual ROS *client library* in c# (or any .net language, really). [ros.net](https://github.com/uml-robotics/ROS.NET) appears to be one, although I cannot say anything about how feature complete it is.

---

Edit: for video, people apparently use [mjpeg_server](http://wiki.ros.org/mjpeg_server).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2